# JPA + Google SQL + GWT + Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jpa-2.0, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to run a simple project.
I'm struggling with some issues.
I created a simple table in a database instance.
Then, following google tutorial, I set up my project in Eclipse.

I raise this error on running from localhost:

```
[EL Severe]: 2012-11-23 14:23:16.915--ServerSession(1241461653)--Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345):     org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions: 
---------------------------------------------------------

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [set] or [get] is not defined in the object [com.shared.Main].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.shared.Main.get(java.lang.String)
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[id-->main.ID]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.shared.Main --> [DatabaseTable(main)])

Exception [EclipseLink-60] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: The method [set] or [get] is not defined in the object [com.shared.Main].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.shared.Main.get(java.lang.String)
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[name-->main.NAME]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.shared.Main --> [DatabaseTable(main)])
```

It seems that eclipse link can't find getter and setter for my object...
Any clue?
My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider></provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://myinstance/test_jpa"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="myuser"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="mypassword"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My eclipse-orm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings version="2.4" xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/orm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_orm_2_4.xsd">
    <entity class="com.shared.Main" access="VIRTUAL">
        <attributes>
            <id name="id" attribute-type="int">
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO"/>
            </id>
            <basic name="name" attribute-type="String">
            </basic>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

My Object:

```
package com.shared;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;


/**
 * The persistent class for the main database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="main")
public class Main implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String name;

    public Main() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved removing the link to the orm file in persistance.xml:

```
<mapping-file>META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml</mapping-file>
```

and adding direct mapping to classes

```
<class>org.my.package.MyClass</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shared folder exists (also) on client. The client can not know anything about databases. SQL etc. Remove all database relations from shared to server.

Comment: Moving the object to the server side doesn't work. Anyway I found some tutorial which add the objects in the model package, then add the package to gwt source which is the same as leaving it in shared, right?

Comment: no, its not the same. I don't know your exact situation so I can only recommend taking it out of shared, sry.

Comment: Brand new project but same result. The weird message "The method [set] or [get] is not defined in the object [com.server.Main]." can be related to a configuration issue or to my (autogenerated) object?

Comment: I do work with persistence. For me it was always happy plug and play without any configurations. I think you are doing something generally wrong. For example normally packages are called com.myproject.client. Not sure if this makes a difference but you should still not work directly on .com level. Does this work without persistence? I did write a turorial http://mwtech74.blogspot.de/2012/08/datastore-adding-and-updating-this-is.html I think it is not exactly what you are trying to achieve but it shows how simple it should be.

Comment: The problem was solved by removing <mapping-file>META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml</mapping-file> and map classes instead of. And btw, everything is working in shared folder cause gwt is taking care to separate the layers. Thank anyway!

Comment: sry I couldn't help and glad it worked out. If you are very nice then answer your question and mark it as answered.